# Office 364 Audit logs: Search-UnifiedAuditLog is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, automation, office365

I was trying to get read the AuditLogs from Office 365 via PowerShell, so we can analyse usage and have the data automatically be updated:

```bsh
# Create/Import remote session (no errors, no warnings)
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking -AllowClobber

Search-UnifiedAuditLog -StartDate $StartDate -EndDate $EndDate -ResultSize 5000 # <- Fails here
```

Error:

```
Search-UnifiedAuditLog : The term 'Search-UnifiedAuditLog' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Was that cmdlet removed or did I miss something?

If this no longer works is there another way to get the audit logs automatically?

Comment: Do any of the other cmdlets work for you? e.g. Get-Mailbox

Comment: They don't give any errors when I run them at least. If I list all commands I also see them (Get-Mailbox,  Get-UnifiedAuditSetting etc.), just not Search-UnifiedAuditLog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I appearently was missing some access rights to Exchange, which meant certain commands were hidden for me.

Comment: I am getting the same error. Can you provide some details on what access rights to Exchange you were missing? Any pointers or direction would help. Thanks

Comment: @skadam85 It seems you have to have exchange admin privileges.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful in providing direction. It looks like I don't and won't be provided Exchange admin access. I finally ended up asking to add my account to a role with view-only audit logs access level. That also helped me run the Search-UnifiedAuditLog command.